# Do I need "cube subclasses" to represent the blocks in a Minecraft-like world?

Tags: software-engineering, data-structure

I would like to try to develop a very simple game like Minecraft for my own education.

My main problem at the moment is figuring out how to model classes that represent the world, which will be made of blocks of various types (such as dirt, stone and sand).

I am thinking of creating the following class structure:

- Cube (with proprerties like color, strength, flammable, gravity) with subclasses:

  - Dirt
  - Stone
  - Sand
  - et cetera

My question is, do I need the Cube subclasses or a single class `Cube` sufficient?

Comment: I would just use a single cube class with an integer typeID + types dictionary.(or maybe a pointer to the relevant entry in the dictionary). I see no need to store the cube parameters in each instance.

Comment: There is no "correct OOP" way, each version has advantages and disadvantages very specific to your use-case. Just make prototypes with each version to see which works best for you, make sure to be prepared for redesign, thats a normal part of software development.

Comment: The computer does not care if a block is Dirt or Stone.  That is a human classification, not one the software needs to know or care about.  Model your classes on what things _do_, not what they _are_.  Prefer composition of interfaces over super-interfaces, and prefer data-driven systems over method overriding system.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, I'd model both the block and the block type as objects. The Cube object should be very lightweight, because you're likely going to have a lot of those instantiated to represent your world. To start with, the Cube object can contain only a pointer to a CubeType (or an appropriately-sized integer that refers to a cube type, if you are even more space-conscious).

The CubeType object itself is where you'd store all the properties of particular types (such as dirt). This allows you to avoid the overhead of duplicating the repeated properties (all dirt blocks being the same color, after all) into every single block.

I see no reason to use inheritance at all for the problem scenario you have described.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance is used when **there is common base functionality that needs to be shared**.

The type-nature of a block (whether its dirt, stone, or lava - you can only be *one* type of block!) would best be implemented by an `enum`

```
enum BlockType { Dirt, Stone, Water, Lava } ;
```

A base object of type `Block` would then be:

```
class Block
{
     BlockType blockType ;
}
```

Based on `blockType` you could then specify properties for that blocktype in any number of ways.  One *simple* way would be to write member functions that return results based on the value of `BlockType`.

```
class Block
{
     BlockType blockType ;
     bool isFlammable() {
         return blockType == Lava ;
     }
     bool isStone() {
         return blockType == Stone ;
     }
     bool isSolid() {
         return blockType!=Lava && blockType!=Water ; // only nonsolid types
     }
}
```

This is flexible and would actually allow blocktypes to change *type* at runtime, which would completely change how they behave instantly.

You could also store a `map<BlockType,BlockProperties>`, where each `BlockType` has a `BlockProperties` object (that lists all its properties).

```
class BlockProperties
{
    bool isFlammable, isSolid ; //etc.
} ;

map< BlockType, BlockProperties > blockProps;

// once at startup,
blockProps[ Dirt ].isSolid = 1 ;
blockProps[ Dirt ].isFlammable = 0 ;
// ...
```

This would be like storing a "prototype" of each base object.  Per-block customizable properties would go directly in `class Block` (such as an HP member).  Class-level properties per-block (such as `maxHp`, or `damageResistance`) would go in `BlockProperties`.

Comment: You might end up with flammable water here. Most parameters would be constant for all instances of a specific type.

Comment: I agree with Gir. I can have 1millions block of Dirt, with same constant parameter and 2millions block of Stone with same constant parameter (for stone)...

Comment: @Gir Good point, edited.

Comment: Now assume you have 200 types of blocks. Some flammable while others are not.  isFlamable() and isSolid() are going to be quite long and hard to maintain.

Comment: But it's dynamic and makes for easy changing of settings during playtesting.  Possibly not that useful for blocktypes though.  You could also store a map of `map<BlockType,BlockProperties>`, where each `BlockType` has a `BlockProperties` object (that lists all its properties).

Answer (score 2):

I think your line of reason is good for the moment. A very good rule of thumb when designing classes is to avoid adding stuff that are not needed **yet**. What I mean is that if you think about a feature that might be needed in the future, perhaps you should leave it to be included in the model later on, when it is really needed and (perhaps) you will have a better understanding of what is required. By experience, this avoids clamping the solution.

For instance, in your case one could think about having an intermediate inheritance between Cube and the children Dirt and Sand, since they are smaller (than Stone, for instance) and might share dust-like properties. If that is not a current need, forget about it and keep it simple.

I would not go with the solution of having just a type ID. First of all, because in that way you will not be able to rely on the benefits from the object orientation.

Also, I have this feeling that as your game gets developed you will eventually/possibly identify the need to have shared properties or behaviours in a fashion that resembles the Bridge Design Pattern. If you don't known the pattern yet, it is definitely worthwhile reading about it (some references [here](http://game-engineering.blogspot.com.br/2008/07/bridge-pattern-vs-strategy-pattern.html) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434352/Understanding-and-Implementing-Bridge-Pattern-in-C)). :)

EDIT: I do think the answer given by @bobobobo is very good indeed. And one suggestion to properly address the points correctly noted could be the use of a bridge pattern like the following:

[image: Bridge between Block (type) and BlockProperty classes]

In that way, the map suggested in one of the commentaries would allow to configure a very comprehensive range of block types with different properties. For instance, a block could be breakable and flammable by having instances of the two corresponding property classes, children from BlockProperty. The maintenance shall be easy (need a new type? just create a new child from BlockProperty) and updating blocks in the game/prototype is just a matter of iterating through the map (as @bobobobo already mentioned).

Comment: I think using OOP concepts for this is an overkill and can lead to unnecessary complications. The original minecraft uses block ID+subID http://www.minecraftinfo.com/IDList.htm

Comment: I beg to differ. OOP is mainly a concept model (a way of thinking the problem), which in fact makes easier the understanding of the problem domain and the maintainance of the solution. Sure, there is a learning curve involved, but my experience shows that is worthwhile. Also, compilers are quite clever in optimizing the code. Nevertheless, since the question states *educational purposes*, I really don't think this is the issue here.

Comment: Also, if you would please indulge me another argument (considering that I do not play Minecraft - I am just judging this based on the link you provided), the fact that Minecraft uses Id numbers to spawn blocks does not necessarily mean that the implementation is not object oriented.

Comment: One thing I've learned when it comes to OOP is that everyone has his own version of OOP. Cause everyone is right! /s

Comment: I think that using IDs will be easier to maintain at the expense of flexibility.I am trying to avoid duplicating parameters. Assuming all stone blocks have the same strength I would prefer a single place where it's stored rather than having a "strength" parameter in each instance. OOP concepts can be used to achieve that as well. For example by hardcoding the strength into a getStrength function.But if you want to add 10 to the strength of all the classes you will need to look in the code of each class.You can also use typeIDs with dictionary items that implement an interface.

Comment: I see your point, but I am not talking about changing several class files. That is exactly my point, having OO will help with that (because you either change code in one place - for the base class - or change each block's property individually). Besides, if all block instances are supposed to have the same value for a given property all the time, why bother to have this configured at all? Adding 10 to the strength of a (sub)set of blocks can be easily achieved with a composite structure, during runtime. And I think that is the point of having a configurable property, right?

Comment: Looks like you are talking about run-time configurable parameters per block instance, while I am assuming compile time configurable parameters per block type.About the +10: Lets say you decided to create a new super-soft block, but strengths=1 to 50 are already used (and balanced). So you will need to add +1 to the strength of all existing block types. If you want to have special,run time configurable parameters per block instance (and not type) inheritance is one of the possible solutions.

Comment: Not really, I was talking about the domain model as a whole (meaning, the classes or block types) - and, in fact, I thought you were talking about runtime configuration! lol Anyway, I guess we are no longer being helpful with this particular duscussion. As @Sidar already mentioned, there is no right or wrong. :)

Comment: Guys, I would have loved to put this comment on the proper answer (the one about using enumeration, given by @bobobobo), but unfortunatelly I don't have enough reputation. I think it is a nice idea, but as others have pointed out there are some concerns. I think that is EXACTLY the situation in which a Bridge pattern would apply. Having only one block class, referencing a base properties class with interesting inheritances for flammable, floatable and whatsover. What do you guys think?